# Reflection vs public method

Tags: php, reflection

While I've learned/studied reflection in the past, I never really dove into use cases (and I'm honestly not sure I'm understanding it's value now either). However, while working on a problem for a personal project, I asked a coworker for thoughts on a problem I was stuck on and he suggested reflection. After some review and doc reading, it got me thinking:

The core of my problem is a property that is `protected static`, and thus can't be accessed outside the class. However, it's turning out I need access to it and while a user of the package would never need to use a method I setup to get the property, I also don't see why I should give them access to the data directly as such. It makes it seem that reflection is a good pattern to follow here, to allow access to the property through the Reflection class, but at the same time, it makes me wonder about just making a public getter for the field.

Am I looking at reflection wrong? From a number of examples I've seen online, I wonder why use reflection instead of making getters? Is it a PHP thing, where other languages (specially typed languages) can use reflection more usefully?

Comment: What do you need access for? It sounds like you need to provide an access method and simply check the privileges of the current user before you return the value.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. A second class needs information from the first, but the user never should. The classes are siblings (from the same parent), so I can't use inheritance as far as I know. Based on your answer, I'm feeling like this has more to do with my lack of experience with reflection, but every tutorial/guide I find feels the same.I'm no closer to understanding practical use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: Thanks thehennyy. I actually did see that question, but as it seems to talk about the benefits in a strictly typed language, thought I'd ask about it in a PHP context.

Comment: Using reflection to get the value of a property sounds wrong to me, I cannot think of an example where I would use that in a production environment.